Intellij 에서 MultiModule 구성
I don't know if I can ask about the IDE, but I can't find it even after searching for days.
First of all, I would like to express my regret.
I configured the multi-module as follows.
Previously, we only had app/api-server and app/mail-server, but this time we created app/authenticatipn-server.
It looks as intended in the Project Viewer, but it is different in Project Structure.

How do I configure app/authentication-server?

Please clarify the ask, how do you like to configure it against what purpose?
